# Powershell execute qdauser remotely

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to run QADuser from a server that I have install the quest cmdlets. 
With remote session in able to add the snapin but I can't run the QADuser

For `get-QADuser -identity xxx00` I receive

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

I run Powershell 2.0 with administrator account and I can't install quest cmdlets on my PC.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use the `Powershell Active Directory Module` from Microsoft?

Comment: yes, hasn't installed AD role and I can't do it.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it may be an authentication problem introduced by the remoting.

If you start with Connect-QADService, and specify the credentials does it work?

Comment: It fails with the same error. I have administrator rights (full administrator/no UAC) in both.